# How to check if any solution exists for a set of linear equations with non negative variables

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, matrix-equations, simplex, gaussian-elimination

Given a set of m equations with n variables x1, x2, … xn and there are more variables than equations (ie n > m and underdetemined)
I am looking for an algorithm (which I will be coding into C#), to find out if there are any solutions with all variables >=0

I don’t really need to know a specific solution (though that’s also nice if it’s easy), just whether any solution exists.

I have investigated the Simplex Method, but I’m hoping there’s something simpler and in-particular doesn’t have the risk of being degenerate or too slow (there will be hundreds of variables / equations)

Comment: Just an idea, but maybe [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) could be used somehow?

Comment: For an LP, hundreds of variables and equations is considered small.

Comment: OK, but how slow is the Simplex Method in a *worst case* scenario? I'm developing a game and don't want a delay to happen in any circumstances.

Comment: Simplex worst case is not a very good practical measure. Interior point methods have a better theoretical bound, but that does not say much about a given LP and a practical implemented algorithm​. No delay at all? I am sure you will need to give the algorithm some cpu cycles.

Comment: Well 100 ms on a 1GHz processor is fine :) So if I am solving with 500 variables will there be cases where Simplex is too slow or even may cycle forever?

Comment: And thanks for your suggestion of Interior Point methods from which I found Karmarkar's algorithm. Is this likely to be a better bet than Simplex for my requirements?

Comment: I don't think any of these algorithms can guarantee to find a solution in 0.1 seconds for 500 equations.

Comment: Hmm. So what if it was 1 second with 200 variables? That would be good enough, but I what i really want is a guarantee it won't *sometimes* take 10 seconds or more, say. As it's a game, lots of different sets of equations will be tried and I don't want the game getting stuck sometimes...